# "No, missing feature: WATCH" when I try to run my smartphone app with wear app?

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I have a smartphone app with a wear app that has been packaged inside of it, similar to the first two steps of this section:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#Studio

I was originally told that my smartphone wasn't running an SDK large enough to support the app (my phone was using KitKat, apparently I needed API 20), so now I am using my Nexus 7 with Android L preview, and this problem has appeared:

[image: Nexus 7 Compatible: No, missing feature: WATCH]

I have a smartwatch emulator and tablet running, and both are connected using the adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601 trick, so I have no idea how to fix this now!

How can I get the smartphone app to run and automatically allow the wear app to install onto the emulator?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In your project you have two applications:

- `Mobile`
- `Wearable`

`Mobile` app should be installed on **mobile device** (phone/tablet) and `Wearable` app should be installed on **Android Wear device**.

This message `No, missing feature: WATCH` means that you're trying to install `Wearable` app on mobile phone - you shouldn't do that, your mobile device is not a WATCH. So once again: just launch `Mobile` app on mobile and `Wearable` app on Android Wear.

> I was originally told that my smartphone wasn't running an SDK large
>   enough to support the app (my phone was using KitKat, apparently I
>   needed API 20), so now I am using my Nexus 7 with Android L preview,
>   and this problem has appeared:

Only the `Wearable` app should require API level 20, but `Mobile` app can target any other SDK level (like 10, 14 etc.). You don't need to set higher SDK level for `Mobile` app only because it supports `Wearable` app.

> How can I get the smartphone app to run and automatically allow the
>   wear app to install onto the emulator?

As described in the tutorial that you've linked:

> If packaged properly, when users download the handheld app, the
>   system automatically pushes the wearable app to the paired wearable.

But please read the note at the top of this page:

> **Note**: This feature doesn't work when you are signing your apps with a
>   debug key when developing. While developing, installing apps with adb
>   install or Android Studio directly to the wearable is required.

This means that automatically installing `Wearable` app after installing `Mobile` app (with `Wearable` app packaged inside) will only work after signing app with your publishing certificate (and not with the debug one - as is done during standard application Launch from Android Studio/Eclipse).

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. Your mention of using adb install near the bottom has been useful also!

Comment: Glad that I could help:) This mention is a quote from the top of that site. Doing `adb install` is basically the same as just launching apps from Android Studio/Eclipse. So during development you just need to launch two applications (`Wearable` to watch and `Mobile` to phone/tablet) separately to two devices.

Comment: I felt so dumb that it was just this problem. This what I get for being a newbie. Thanks!

Answer (score 60):

Please look at this!

[image]

May be you should select the APP item before you launch your app.

Comment: I'm really glad that there's finally a problem that has such an easy solution.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error when I tried running non wearable application on my device and the error was due to some Android Studio issue with misreading the **uses-feature** attribute in the Manifest (it reads required false as true):

```
  <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
        android:required="false"/>
```

If you remove it from the manifest the error will disappear. I think that it should be already fixed in Android Studio 1.4.1 or 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have not open any other android project. I also faced same issue which got solved after I closed android project which has target API greater than watch's.