# Android Wear won't connect to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I was trying to run my app on Android Studio to Android wear (Moto 360) but it gives error.

```
2770c275[Unauthorized - Press'OK' in the 'Allow USB Debugging 'dialog on your device] (missing feature:WATCH)
```

Please help and THANK YOU!!

Comment: Have you (if you can) gone into settings, clicked about and then clicked on build number 7 times? That's how you get developer options (at least on tablets). You can then Allow USB debugging in the Developer options.

Comment: I have already done that. Still getting the error when I run the app

Comment: have a look at [“No, missing feature: WATCH” when I try to run my smartphone app with wear app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621818/no-missing-feature-watch-when-i-try-to-run-my-smartphone-app-with-wear-app). This may help

Comment: I have followed every step, but is still not working

Comment: Try going into Developer Options on the watch and selecting "Revoke debug authorizations", then reconnecting to your computer. You should get a dialog (on the watch) asking to allow ADB from that computer. (Make sure you approve it.)