# Missing feature: WATCH android wear

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

Two days trying to deploy the hello world project into the galaxy Active 2 wear. It is still showing the **missing feature: WATCH**. the project deployed into my mobile correctly but when choosing the *wear* one, it shows up the message: *The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY*
I already read the related problem [like here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621818/no-missing-feature-watch-when-i-try-to-run-my-smartphone-app-with-wear-app/25623405#:%7E:text=Mobile%20app%20should%20be%20installed,device%20is%20not%20a%20WATCH.) but couldn't solve it, here is a screenshot of the wear sdk.
Mobile sdk is:

```
// mobile sdk used
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sensewatch.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

[image: screenshot of the gradle file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AndroidManifest remove this:

```
 `< uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />`
```

and set user library (is in the  AndroidManifest too) to false.

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" />`

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Galaxy Watch Active 2 is running [Tizen OS](https://www.tizen.org/) and not Wear OS by Google.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Android Manifest file all good with respect to the tags and required things then check the target device
[image]